# Creating a "Next Page" on a Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a "Next Page" on my userform. I have added a button on my original userform. Inside the code for this new button what should I write for it to bring the new userform up?

Next step would be to hide the original userform simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your code to this new button put this:

```
Unload Me 'unload your current form
UserForm2.Show 'show your next form called UserForm2
```